# remove property from wordpress core gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

With the new wordpress update there are some new properties that have been added to the core gutenberg blocks to make it easier for certain users to customize these blocks

[image: new quote block]

In the image above you can see the example for the new looks of the quote block. For instance there is now the option to change the appearance of the typography as well as a new 'plain' option for the styles. I want to remove these options, but The only thing i have found so far is how to add extra properties nd how to remove the block entierly.

For the styles, i have found the hook to get the property, but I don't know how i can modify this so it doesn't show the "plain" option:

```
    // hide "plain" opiton inside the style tab of the quote block.
const {
    addFilter,
} = wp.hooks;
addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'jsforwp-advgb/extend-quote-block',
    extendBlockQuoteBlock
);

function extendBlockQuoteBlock( settings, name ) {
    if ( !settings || !settings.supports ) {
        return settings;
    }
    if ( 'core/quote' !== name ) return settings;
    console.log( settings.styles );

    return settings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Block styles can be removed with `unregisterBlockStyle(blockName, styleVariationName)`. There is no need extend or add a filter to the block registration, just use `unregisterBlockStyle` when the DOM is ready to prevent a race condition:

```ls
wp.domReady( function () {
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/quote', 'plain' );
} );
```

Ref: [Block Editor Handbook / Reference Guides / Block API Reference / Styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/)

**Update:** Below is a screenshot showing the effect of running `wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/quote', 'plain' )` in the console.
[image: unregisterBlockStyle]

If you wish to remove typography, it is different to block styles and is from the block supports API, which is done with addFilter and lodash assign to remove support for the features you dont want, eg:

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'jsforwp-advgb/extend-quote-block',
    extendBlockQuoteBlock
);

function extendBlockQuoteBlock(settings, name) {
    if (name !== 'core/quote') {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        supports: lodash.assign({}, settings.supports, {
            typography: false,
        }),
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i actually don''t want to remove the block entierly, i just want to remove some of its options

Comment: @Nami It doesn't remove the block, it just removes the block style "plain" only, the block remains. You can test this by opening up the console and running just `wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/quote', 'plain' );` when you have a quote block on the page.

Comment: my bad you are actually right, i tried doing the same to remove the typography tab on the right though and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Nami That's okay, typography is different to block styles which can be removed via [block supports API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#typography)