# Remove/hide "additional CSS" tab in wordpress gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am looking for a way to hide this option in the gutenberg blocks. In this example you can see that the core/separator has the option to add "aditional CSS" and that is something I don't want to allow the client to do.

Any way to hide this?

[image: core/separator Image]

Comment: it is just classes though - they aren't able to write css in that

Comment: Use CSS to hide the panel `block-editor-block-inspector__advanced`

Answer (score 0):

The additional CSS classes section can be enabled/disabled by setting [className in the Block Supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/#classname) to `true|false`. Any property that is part of `supports:{...}` can be disabled in the same way as `typography` ([see related answer to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71637137/remove-property-from-wordpress-core-gutenberg-block/71642325#71642325)), eg:

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'jsforwpadvgb/extend-quote-block',
    extendBlockQuoteBlock
);

function extendBlockQuoteBlock(settings, name) {
    if (name !== 'core/quote') {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign({}, settings, {
        supports: lodash.assign({}, settings.supports, {
            typography: false, // Previous question 71637137
            className: false // Removes "Additional CSS classes" panel for blocks that support it
            customClassName: false // **Updated** For blocks that don't have className
        }),
    });
}
```

Ref: [Block Editor Handbook / Reference Guides / Filter Reference / Block Filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype)

If you want to remove different options for many blocks, the best way to find the name of the option is to view the block.json source (eg. [quote](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/quote/block.json)) to find the properties it supports and then disabled/enable what you wish.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I think 'className' is not the right setting i need to target since it did nothing for me. I noticed that not all blocks have 'classname' in their support object. Maybe that is an old approach that does not work with the new update? I tried it for all blocks and also for the separator block. But it does nothing for me. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @Nami Tested and works with WordPress 5.9.2 - the above example is targeting the quote block with `(name !== 'core/quote')`. Did you alter that line to whichever block you want it to apply to? Also, when testing, double-check that you are clearing the browser cache (eg shift + f5) so you sure you are seeing the latest changes you made, its most common issue why things 'don't work'.

Comment: yup, cleared my cache and all, but nothing :( only thing i am doing different is changing the lodash. for the Object. but that should not be the issue no?

Comment: @Nami I've just tested with the latest version of the Gutenberg plugin deactivated, for blocks that dont have 'className', use `customClassName` and it removes the custom CSS

Comment: yes! it goes away with using `customClassName`, but then i get these errors on the console  https://storage.googleapis.com/shared-files-mrhenry/imane/resourceful-scorpion-0444c1e813.17.22.png